# Simple issue with jQuery Chained Select Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Chained Select Menu built with Javascript works almost perfectly:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/seqL2cfo/

However, when I select `US > Alaska` then back to `Choose a State...`, all the `US` results disappear. Then when I change the default country to `Choose a Country...`, all results disappear.

Why can it not return to the default state?

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery('#cat').change(function () {
    var val = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery("#statecat").toggle(val == "us");

    if (val == "0") 
        jQuery('#countries_select').siblings('div').show();
    else {
        jQuery('form').siblings('div').hide();
        jQuery('.' + val).show();
    }
});

jQuery('#statecat').change(function() {
    jQuery('.state1').hide();
    jQuery('.' + jQuery(this).val()).show();
});


jQuery("#countries_select select").change(function(){
    console.log(jQuery(this).val())

    if( jQuery(this).val() == "us"){
        jQuery("#state_select").show();
    } else {
        jQuery("#state_select").hide();
    }

    jQuery("ul.countries > li").hide()
    jQuery("ul.countries ." + jQuery(this).val() ).css("display", "block")
})
```

Thank you

Comment: `jQuery('#cat').change(function ()` and `jQuery("#countries_select select").change(function()` refer to the same form and basicly the same event, but do different things. Why don't you put them in one function? This way it will be more clear what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if the value of the select is 0 / empty then show all the countries / states:

```
if(jQuery(this).val()  == ''){
      jQuery("ul.countries > li").show()
}else{
    jQuery("ul.countries > li").hide()
    jQuery("ul.countries ." + jQuery(this).val() ).css("display", "block")        
}
```

Updated Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/seqL2cfo/1/

Comment: Thank you for this @Jeroen. Can you show me briefly how I implement this into my current JS solution? *spots Fiddle*

Comment: yes added the udpated fiddle a second ago to my answer.